# Different results for coding bat and eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm doing the coding bat exercises for Java and I came across a problem where eclipse returns the correct value while the coding bat environment does not.
The problem I am working on is:

Given a string and a non-empty substring sub, compute recursively if at least n copies of sub appear in the string somewhere, possibly with overlapping. N will be non-negative.

```
strCopies("catcowcat", "cat", 2) → true
strCopies("catcowcat", "cow", 2) → false
strCopies("catcowcat", "cow", 1) → true
```

For the case strCopies("iiijjj", "i", 3) my code ran in coding bat returns false while in eclipse it return true. For all the other cases my code returns the same value in eclipse as in coding bat. As I already experienced inexplicable behavior in the coding bat environment, could this be an error?

I call the method by:

```
System.out.println(p.strCopies("iiijjj", "i", 3));
```

My code is:

```
int count;
public boolean strCopies(String str, String sub, int n) {
 if (str.indexOf(sub) != -1) {
   count++;
   strCopies(str.substring(str.indexOf(sub)+1), sub, n);
 }
 if (count == n) {
   return true;
 }
 else {
   count = 0;
 return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't return the correct answer for ("iiijjj", "i", 2) for example. If called twice in a row with ("iiijjj", "i", 3), it returns true the first time, and false the second time. So, basically, you need to rethink your algorithm. Don't use any field. Only local variables and return values. And stop as soon as possible: if n is 0, you know the answer. If not, your goal should be to make n go towards 0.

Comment: I tried your suggestions in eclipse..With ("iiijjj", "i", 2) I get false. With ("iiijjj", "i", 3) I get true even with multiple calls.

Comment: Probably because you recreated a new instance of your class to call the method again. Just call `System.out.println(p.strCopies("iiijjj", "i", 3));` twice, and you'll see that it doesn't return true twice.

Comment: Proof: http://ideone.com/O33rKv

Comment: Thanks, you are right. It will not reach the else part to reset the counter so in the second call it will evaluate to false.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution

```
public boolean strCopies(String str, String sub, int n) {

  if(str.isEmpty() && n > 0 ) return false;
  if(str.isEmpty() && n == 0 ) return true;

  if( str.length() >= sub.length() && 
  str.substring(0,sub.length()).equals(sub) ){
    return strCopies( str.substring(1) , sub , n-1 );
  }

  return strCopies(str.substring(1) , sub , n);

}
```